# Highest performance on slicing objects on an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I want to reduce the size of an array in-memory of my NodeJS server.

I want to send only the 'header' of each object in the array, reducing the network traffic. I have this array on the server:

```
var lotOfThings = [
  {name: 'Watson', role: 'Mod', lotOfData: ... },
  {name: 'Sherlock', role: 'Admin', lotOfData: ...}
];
```

I want to remove `lotOfData` from all the objects within `lotOfThings` and send back to the user only this:

```
  {name: 'Watson', role: 'Mod'},
  {name: 'Sherlock', role: 'Admin'}
```

How can I achieve this with a good performance?

Comment: I'm a bit confused by what you've described. Are you looking to simply take a subset of `lotOfThings`, or are you looking to send each item in `lotOfThings` minus the irrelevant keys denoted by `lotOfData`?

Comment: Each item in lotOfThings minus the irrelevant keys denoted by lotOfData. Exactly.

Comment: In that case, see @pwilmot's answer below. You're unlikely to squeeze more performance out of it as you've described. If you are processing this array for each request though, you might consider additionally caching the mapped version described below so you can amortize the cost of generating it in the first place.

Comment: Nice catch, @cmw. Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to remove `lotOfData` permanently from your array of objects or only temporarily when sending the array back to a requester?  The answer to this determines whether you can just modify the current array or have to make a sub-set copy.

Comment: I want a sub-set. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Plain JS:

```
lotOfThings.map(function(thing) {
    return { name: thing.name, role: thing.role };
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I love plain JS options!

Comment: I liked you, @penne12, may we talk? [This is me](https://plus.google.com/u/0/+RodrigoNascimentodeSouzaRodmentou)

Comment: @Rodmentou I'm normally in the [JS or Ruby chat rooms](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/?tab=all&sort=active) here - for privacy reasons, I won't chat offsite.

Comment: Ohh, thanks, @penny12. I wanted to talk in private about you. You seem to have The same age and knowledge path of my brother. But thanks, anyway, I do understand. :)

Answer (score 3):

using underscore.js

```
_.map(lotOfThings, 
    function(thing) {
        return { name: thing.name, role: thing.role };
    }
);
```

Comment: if you only want a single attribute you can use the _.pluck function but for multiple attributes you need to use _.map over all elements

Comment: Thanks for your answer.